# Enable OCR in Greenshot

Tags: windows-10, scanning, ocr, greenshot

I run `Windows 10` with `Microsoft Office professional Plus 2016` on my computer. Looks like MS OCR functionality is enabled in my system since `OneNote` is able to copy text from image.

But how to enable this functionality for `Greenshot`? Currently I have following menu after making screenshot:

[image]

I does not have OCR.

And there is no OCR plugin listed in settings:

[image]

But OCR plugin file exist:

[image]

UPD

During installation OCR option was enabled.

[image]

How to enable `Greenshot` OCR plugin in my system?

UPD 2

I have installed MODI manually according MS recomendation Method 1:

```
Method 1: Download and install MDI to TIFF File Converter

To download and install MDI to TIFF File Converter, go to the following Microsoft website:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30328
```

After that I have reinstalled GS, but this not helped. Still no OCR in menu
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enable OCR in Greenshot**

> [How can I use Greenshot for OCR?](http://getgreenshot.org/faq/how-can-i-use-greenshot-for-ocr/)
>
> For the Greenshot OCR (Optical Character Recognition) plug-in to work
> we are depending on a component from Microsoft called MODI (Microsoft
> Office Document Imaging). If this is installed Greenshot will activate
> the plugin (if installed) and you will have an OCR destination. If you
> select this destination the OCR logic from Microsoft will try to
> detect the text on the screenshot and Greenshot will place this on the
> clipboard. MODI can be installed as an option from the Microsoft
> Office 2003 / 2007 installer or as an option from the free Microsoft
> SharePoint Designer 2007 ( you can find a description and a link to
> download it under “method 2″ here:
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760

---

Essentially it looks as if you need to download and install something that contains the MODI components. Once this is installed then the Greenshot software is supposed to activate the plug-in that gives it the OCR functionality.

If you cannot find this in the Greenshot software once the MODI components are installed, then try uninstalling Greenshot and reinstalling it.

[image]

Comment: During installation OCR feature was enabled. More details in UPD. Uninstall/not helped.

Comment: @vico Yes, but you want to ensure that you follow the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760 and install one of those first, and then check the OCR functionality within Greenshot afterwards. If it's not available after that, then uninstall Greenshot and reinstall after the MODI components are installed. Regardless of what the installation asks for OCR functionality and what it allows you to install with it's software, you likely need to follow the instructions of the MS KB as suggested first and then check or uninstall then reinstall GS. Give that a try and then report back your results.

Comment: I was trying MS Method 1, but this not helped. More details in UPD 2

Comment: @vico Well it appears that [this article](https://greenshot.atlassian.net/browse/BUG-1268) is suggesting to try method #2 from the MS KB rather than method #1 so while this is referring to Win 7 and Office 2010, it may be applicable to what you're running as well perhaps? You might ensure you're installing the latest version of Greenshot too in case it's a version issue.

Answer (score 13):

For those of you who for some reason or another can't/won't install SharePoint Designer, I've found a nice alternative solution, using the FOSS [Capture2Text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/).

[image: HowTo screenshot]

The software comes with both a GUI and a CLI executable. You can either add the CLI to your `$PATH` or just direct a new external command in Greenshot to the file's location, as in my example.

Then add the following arguments: 
`-i "{0}" --clipboard`

Where `-i` stands for `input` and specifies the input picture, in our case `"{0}"`, which Greenshot will replace with the clipboarded screenshot.
`--clipboard`, you'll be surprised to hear, means that the output OCR text will be copied to the clipboard.

Further documentation for both the CLI and the GUI can be found on the project's SourceForge homepage, linked above.

Comment: went for this because of challenges with finding "sharepoint designer", worries about 64 vs 32 bit, and the other answer that said the MS OCR isn't any good anyways. . .  this worked, first try :)  Thank you for the detailed instructions ~

Comment: Brilliant alternative! I use --line-breaks as additional option:
"-i "{0}" --clipboard --line-breaks" to keep them. Another PLUS: The integrated spell checking! It's really worth a try. Thanks for this Tip.

Comment: @SiL3NC3 Will FOSS auto-dectect the language or do I have to specifiy it in the CLI?

Comment: OMG this really works !

Answer (score 5):

You also need to install MODI (Microsoft Office Document Imaging)

Go on following page and execute method 2 (this worked for me)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982760/install-modi-for-use-with-microsoft-office-2010

> **Method 2: Install MODI by installing SharePoint Designer 2007**

> SharePoint Designer 2007 is provided as a free download from the Microsoft Download Center. To download SharePoint Designer 2007 and only include MODI during the installation, follow these steps:

> 1. Download and run the SharePointDesigner.exe file from this location: [Download SharePoint Designer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21581)

> 2. Review, and then accept the software license.

> 3. Click **Customize** to open the installation options.

> 4. On the **Installation Options** tab, click the down arrow and select **Not Available** for these three sections:

> - Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer

- Office Shared Features
- Office Tools.

> 5. Expand Office Tools
> 6. Click the down arrow for the Microsoft Office Document Imaging option, and then select Run all from my computer.
> 7. Click Install Now, and then click Close.

### Download no longer working

As mention in the answer from OneSource (https://superuser.com/a/1128277/690285) the SharePoint Designer 2007 is no longer available for download. But he posted a link to https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-SharePoint-Designer-2007/3000-2064_4-75451282.html

> Be aware for potential harms of the download link, as it is not an official download from Microsoft.

Comment: Only the 2nd method worked for me too.

Comment: Once i installed the SharePoint Designer Microsoft Imaging Option the OCR plugin appeared in Greenshot when I restarted it. Also, the "Copy text from picture" option in OneNote appeared

Answer (score 4):

The new way is to just save an image with Greenshot, then copy and paste into OneNote, right click the image, Copy Text from Picture, then paste OCRed text.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_windows8/office-2013-and-installing-ocr-for-documenting/ab7078a3-fd67-4199-a722-6a0596b838a0?auth=1
https://quietsoundz.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/ocr-in-office-2013/

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't find the SharePoint Designer download on Microsoft's site because it's not available any more, you can get it here: https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-SharePoint-Designer-2007/3000-2064_4-75451282.html After I downloaded it, I followed the instructions for Method 2 above and everything worked great! OCR in Greenshot was available after I restarted it ...

Answer (score 1):

The method presented above indeed works, but, for now, the OCR it makes is poor. Follows an example:

Step 1) I made a Greenshot's OCR of the following screen capture :

[Captured Image with Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYz7Y.png)

The result was : 
Hosted Wths 
Language Setbrigs Tool

Step 2) Using 'Abbyy Screenshot Reader', that I had already instaled, I made an OCR of the same capture.

The result was perfect: 
Hosted Webs 
Language Settings Tool

Conclusion : 
=> No errors with 'Abbyy Screenshot Reader' against  
=> 5 errors in 33 letters with the Microsoft's OCR used by Greenshot.  
IMHO, it is well worth to install Abby Fine Reader version 11 only to get access to the included 'Abbyy Screenshot Reader'.

PS: But I also love Greenshot for image capture. So that I have donated some to the developers. :) Greenshot is by far the best screen capture software I have used, and I use this kind of software for decades, and from time to time I searched better options. Now, I feel no need to search again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more convenient way to use **Capture2Text_CLI.exe** as your OCR plugin (as posted by another user). Once it's run the OCR, it then loads and passes the text to Notepad++.

Firstly, create a Powershell script with the following content and save it as **ClipToNotepad.ps1** (or similar).

```
Param($snap)

& "C:\Program Files\Capture2Text\Capture2Text_CLI.exe" -i $snap --clipboard

Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$clipboardText = Get-Clipboard
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^v")
```

You may need to edit the paths to Capture2Text_CLI.exe and notepad++.exe if they are installed in different locations.

Place the script in a suitable location. I put mine in the Greenshot install folder.

Now, in the External Command Editor of Greenshot, add a new entry

- Name: `OCR to Notepad` or whatever
- Command: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Argument: `-File "C:\Program Files\Greenshot\ClipToNotepad.ps1" -snap "{0}"`

You will likely need to change the **ExecutionPolicy** for Powershell scripts for this to work. So, try

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2007 is not available anymore on Microsofts webpage, but MODI is part of Office 2007 too.
It works well on Windows 10  1809.